# Photo Viewer only prints black and white

Tags: windows-7, windows-photo-viewer, color-printer

This is a very odd problem. I have a color printer (HP deskjet 3070A) and a Windows 7 machine. When I print email or text documents, color works just fine. However, when I try to print from the photo viewer, the image always comes out in black and white! Paint similarly cannot print in color, nor can pain.net.

I have tried enabling color correction, re-disabling it, searched the print options and properties for something about "turn on color" (no luck). If I print a test page (from the print options dialog), it comes out perfectly fine, in color.

I'm sure you understand this is a very frustrating problem. It's pretty clear the hardware is not a fault, but something seems seriously wrong with the software. What can I do to print my photos (besides pasting them in Word)?

Answer (score -1):

simply right-click over the pictures icon (not open it up) and select print from the gray pop-up menu that shows up when you right-click over the picture.  Before you select to actually print it, you will see "options" and from here you can select to go to "Printer Properties" (you can also get to this by right-clicking over the printer's icon in the printer's folder and selecting "Printer Properties") but this option seems to be only related to photos and its software.  Once you are in Printer Properties, you will see "Advanced Settings." Check here for me to ensure "Grayscale" is OFF.